# How to configure NServiceBus endpoints when exposing more than one method in WCF service contract

Tags: c#, wcf, nservicebus

I'm studing the NServiceBus integration with Wcf sample:

[WcfIntegration sample on github](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/IntegrationTests/WcfIntegration)

I'd like to extend ICancelOrderService with a second method like so:

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface ICancelOrderService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ErrorCodes Process(CancelOrder request);
    [OperationContract]
    ErrorCodes ProcessAnotherMessage(PlaceOrder request);
}
```

As far as I understand I should add new service inhereted from WcfService

```
public class PlaceOrderService : WcfService<CancelOrder, ErrorCodes>
{
}
```

and corresponding PlaceOrderHandler:

```
public class PlaceOrderHandler : IHandleMessages<PlaceOrder>
{
    private readonly IBus bus;

    public PlaceOrderHandler(IBus bus)
    {
        this.bus = bus;
    }

    public void Handle(PlaceOrder message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("===========PLACE ORDER message============");

        if (message.OrderId % 2 == 0)
            bus.Return((int)ErrorCodes.Fail);
        else
            bus.Return((int)ErrorCodes.None);
    }
}
```

Server's app.config contains the following configuration:

```
<services>
  <service name="Server.WebServices.CancelOrderService" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9009/services/cancelOrder" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Questions:

1. How to configure app.config for the second PlaceOrderService?
2. It seems that method name in service contract (Process or ProcessAnotherMessage) just ignored by NServiceBus - i don't see any usings of the method name just TRequest/TResponse type parameters used:

   CancelOrderService : WcfService<**CancelOrder**, **ErrorCodes**>

I think it's too havy way - for each new method/message that I'm going to send create new WcfService type, handler and configure app.config. Am I missing something?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/sfarmar/supportcode/tree/master/WcfIntegration_6179.1, Dose theis help?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration for the second endpoint can be set up using VS tool - wcf config tool: right click on app.config ->edit wcf configuration ->create new service and follow wizards steps to setup a new endpoint.

also [this video (WCF using C#: Building your first WCF application)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1o_1trg2R04)
 can be useful  (endpoint is setting up on the 30-35 mins)